# Sharing html text on Android via WhatsApp broken

Tags: android, whatsapp

Can't share html from my own android app via WhatsApp from latest WhatsApp update.

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
shareIntent.setType("text/html");
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(htmlText));
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_HTML_TEXT, htmlText);
```

This opens intent chooser, WhatsApp is there. After selecting it asks to select contact to share, but "send" button does nothing.

BTW, sharing for "text/plain" still works fine. Any ideas?

Comment: try downloading the latest apk and analyse it (check it's android manifest for filters)

Answer (score 0):

changing

```
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(htmlText));
```

to

```
htmlIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(htmlText).toString());
```

fixed issue.

Comment: This sent plain text and not the html formatted text. can you post solution for html text to share.